# Quick Problem - Extracting numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

I need to extract a single variable number from a string. The string always looks like this:

```
javascript:change(5);
```

with the variable being 5.
How can I isolate it? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way, assuming the number is always surrounded by parentheses:

```
var str = 'javascript:change(5);';
var lastBit = str.split('(')[1];
var num = lastBit.split(')')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes great sense.
Very grateful for the other solutions too.

Comment: A down-vote because someone is just too big a fan of regexes to let this go?

Comment: Or because it's unnecessarily complicated, with unneeded temporaries, and the problem spec is quite simply "find the number among this stuff that's not number"? `/(\d+)/` is the simplest way to do that, and `/javascript:change\((\d+)\);/` additionally verifies that the surrounding data is in the expected form. `split` is excessively clever.

Comment: @hobbs - disagree, because the OP is clearly interested in grabbing an actual parameter from a function call (be it a number or whatever) and this will work irrespective of the (contents). The regex solution breaks for anything else.

Comment: @karim79 - not irrespective on the contents. It breaks for `javascript:change('(5)');`. In fact yours will only return `'` - the regexp will just fail...  I'd rather get no parameter found than a `'` back from this sort of function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html):-

```
var test = "javascript:change(5);"
var number = new RegExp("\\d+", "g")
var match = test.match(number);

alert(match);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple RegExp can solve this one:

```
var inputString = 'javascript:change(5);';
var results = /javascript:change\((\d+)\)/.exec(inputString);
if (results)
{
  alert(results[1]);  // 5
}
```

Using the `javascript:change` part in the match as well ensures that if the string isn't in the proper format, you wont get a value from the matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = 'javascript:change(5);', result = str.match(/\((\d+)\)/);

if ( result ) {
    alert( result[1] ) 
}
```